# fread() binary mode not working properly in c++

Tags: c++, io

I was facing a problem with the `fread()` function while coding in c++ .
The target is to open a file in binary mode for writing using :
`fopen_s(&filename,filelocation,"wb");` , write a string and an int to be precise using `fwrite(&buffer,size_of_read,count,filename)` and then to read back the data into other variables (note that this may seem foolish to write and then read data from the same file in the same program, but this is just for testing purpose, since the project I am working on is strictly based upon encryption, and this is one of the modules)...

Here's my code :

```
int x = 1;                              // this is piece of data to write to the file
FILE *src;                              // the file variable that I am using
string text = "byebye";                 // this happens to be the piece of data
src = fopen("F:\\_log.log", "wb");      // open file in binary write mode
fwrite(&text, 1, 7, src);               // that's 7 because of 6 characters plus '\0'
fwrite(&x, 4, 1, src);                  // 4 bytes for int ---> writing x=1 to file
text.clear();                           // for verification purpose
fclose(src);
src = fopen("F:\\_log.log", "rb");
int y = 0;                              // this is the int that will contain read data
string read;                            // string that contains read data
fread(&read, 1, 7, src);                // read the data and store in read
fread(&y, 4, 1, src);                   // read the stored int into y
cout << "string is : " << read << "\nNumber is : " << y << endl;
```

The output of the above program seems to be correct for integers but not for strings...

```
string is : 
Number is : 1
```

The `Number is : 1` statements clears that first `y` was zero but the data from the file had been successfully read and stored in `y` which then turned to `1`

But, if the integer has been correctly read, then why not the string `read`
Also, there seems to be a sync in `text` and `read` because if I change the command `text.clear();` to `text="higuys";` then the output is :

```
string is : higuys
Number is : 1
```

How do I solve this ? (completely unable to understand what in the world is being processed in that code...)

Additional information (though it may not do much good) :

OS : Windows 10

IDE : codeblocks (tried with visual studio too)

Compiler : GNU GCC

Debugger : GDB

I have tried to check for any errors using `perror();` and tricks like `cout<<fread(&read,1,7,src)<<endl;` to check the number of bytes read, but everything was OK. Please help me with this one.....

EDIT :

OK, I have tried using array of `char` instead of `string` and it worked !!
But still, one thing is not clear and that is : why are the two strings `text` and `read` in sync ?

Comment: You can't write a `std::string` object using `fwrite`, and not read it with `fread` either. Not any complex object actually. It will just not work. You might want to search for and read about *serialization*. Oh, and if you're wondering about the reason you can't write `std::string` object like that, it's because basically what a `std::string` object contains is the string length and a pointer to the actual string, writing a pointer to a file will not work very well.

Comment: Also you do not need to write the null terminating char to the file. The file is already of a known size.

Comment: So, should I try to convert the string in an array of characters and then write/read it ?

Comment: That's *one* way to solve it, but if the strings can be of variable length, you need to store the length as well so you know how much to read (or store the terminator, and read byte by byte). That is one way to *serialize* a string. Oh, and you don't really need a new array for this, you already have an "array" which you can get by using e.g. `text.c_str()` (can't be used when reading though, though `&text[0]` should work if you set the size beforehand)

Comment: Your title mentions C++ but your code does not reflect that. I would suggest using the C++ [io lib](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iolibrary/)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Thanks, got it !! Also, as I have mentioned, this is a module of my encryption-based project. I do write the string size in the file.  Anyways, thanks for the effort.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi : The project I am working on is a Win32 Console-based app which is optimised by the IDE to use c++ credentials, hence the tag `c++`.

Comment: That's all assuming that the file open succeeds, something that you don't seem to check for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
string read;
```

to

```
char read[7];
```

string is a class and not a buffer, so you cannot fread giving the address of a string object.

If the program is not only for a fixed 7 bytes string and not only C (you tagged the question as C++) then you should consider using ifstream/ofstream and string and write/read using operators << and >>.

Comment: Though I am considering to input a string and then convert it to `char[string.length];` and that is because : due to some reason, when whitespace is stored into a `char[]` it doesn't seem to hold it and when it is printed with `cout<<` , there is no whitespace. This is the reason why I used strings.

Comment: @Wormhole Surely your string can contain spaces. Maybe you read it with some other function (scanf) which stops at the first whitespace!?